# How to find tag name given a text in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div class='mydiv'><p style='xyz'>123</p><p>456</p><p style='xyz'>789</p><p>abc</p></div>", 'lxml')
```

Now, I have a text '456'.

I want to find the text in the all the tags which have the same tag name containing the text '456'.

That is, in the html, `<p>456</p>` contains `456`, then we should find `abc` because of `<p>abc</p>` but not `123` and `789` because `<p style>` in `<p style='xyz'>123</p>` and `<p style='xyz'>789</p>`.

Note that `<p>` above can be other tag, such as `<div>`.

Searching `soup.find('p')` should be avoided.

The final result is `[456, 789]`.

It is a bit complicated.

How can we solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print all tags that share tag name and tag attributes with tag that contains string "456":

```
txt = '''
    <div class='mydiv'>
        <p style='xyz'>123</p>
        <p>456</p>
        <p style='xyz'>789</p>
        <p>abc</p>
    </div>'''

text_to_find = '456'
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

tmp = soup.find(lambda t: t.contents and t.contents[0] == text_to_find)
if tmp:
    for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == tmp.name and t.attrs == tmp.attrs):
        print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
<p>456</p>
<p>abc</p>
```

---

For input "123":

```
<p style="xyz">123</p>
<p style="xyz">789</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Andrej.

Answer (score 0):

Theres actually multiple ways, here are two examples how you could find what you are looking for:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<div class='mydiv'><p style='xyz'>123</p><p>456</p><p style='xyz'>789</p><p>abc</p></div>", 'lxml')

# Find all tags first and then look for the one matching your string
found = [x for x in soup.findAll() if x.text == "456"]

for p in found:
  print(p)

# Using findAll functionality directly
found = soup.findAll(text="456")

for p in found:
  print(p)
```

> <p>456</p>
> 456

Note however, using the second method you recieve `NavigableString` objects and not `Tag` objects!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<div class='mydiv'><p style='xyz'>123</p><p>456</p><p style='xyz'>789</p><p>abc</p></div>", 'html5lib')

tags = soup.find_all()
for tag in tags:
    if tag.get('style'):
        tag.extract()

for tag in soup.select('html body'):
    print(tag.get_text('\n'))
```

prints:

```
456
abc
```